# Isolated Storage

Tags: c#-3.0, isolatedstorage

Can I Store a Access Database in Isolated Storage?
If I can what is the Connection String?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will work, but try this:

```
Type isolatedStorageType = ISStore.GetType();
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piRootDirectory = isolatedStorageType.GetProperty("RootDirectory", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(piRootDirectory.GetValue(ISStore, null).ToString(), fileName);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fullPath);
```

Once you have the full path, you can use it in your connection string as you normally would.

Answer (score -1):

You can store files in isolated storage, Access Data is a file, so you can

Comment: Technically you can store any serializable data, including connection string. However this is not best practice to store them on client's machine.

Comment: Its obvious to me that the poster wanted to know how to USE the access database file in his application (hence the question about connection string).  The question is how to connect to the database once the file is in isolated storage.